# How to execute echo cmd on remote ssh command

Tags: ssh, shell

I have the following line which does not work:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 root@$serverip "echo 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' > /etc/resolv.conf && sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service"
```

As I somehow need to put nameserver 1.1.1.1 in some other type of quoting here I guess. Can smb help?

Comment: The line works for me exactly as it is. What is not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Your command works. But your invokation of `systemctl restart resolvconf` overwrites your changes again. You need to configure resolvconf properly instead of writing to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: If i simply do: >>ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 root@$serverip echo 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' > /etc/resolv.conf<<
I get back Bad port ''Server'

Comment: That rather sounds like $serverip contains something wrong.

Comment: The error message you get can be reproduced using the parameter `-p Server`. `-p` expects the port of the SSH server.

Comment: Also came accross the xD pretty stupid ... Its working, now for me!